# How to cope u prefix utf-8 string( need to decode but fail by `u` )?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I am using python build a web base file manager with python 3 compatibility.

Every file header is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals, absolute_import
```

Then I found something wrong due to Unicode.

My system is Chinese,  I have a folder named `E:\filemanager\data\c - 副本`.

I use `ajax GET` send (`E:\filemanager\data\c - 副本`) to the flask app(filemanager). I also confusing when I meet the `Windows Error[3]` which indicate path not exists. Then I use pycharm to debug my code, and see the string has already became `u'E:\\filemanager\\data\\c - \xe5\x89\xaf\xe6\x9c\xac'` when `os.listdir(path)`.

This string is horrible. Let me show the problem:

```
>>> p1 = ur'E:\filemanager\data\c - 副本'
>>> p1
u'E:\\filemanager\\data\\c - \u526f\u672c'
>>> p1.encode('utf-8')
'E:\\filemanager\\data\\c - \xe5\x89\xaf\xe6\x9c\xac'
# here you can see this result just like p2 without `u` prefix

>>> p2 = u'E:\\filemanager\\data\\c - \xe5\x89\xaf\xe6\x9c\xac'
>>> p2.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\kasim\Envs\fmgr\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 24-29: ordinal not in range(128)
```

There is a `u` prefix in `p2`! Which make me can not list the directory(because the name is wrong).

I know only remove that `u` prefix can make decode successful. But How to remove it ?

---

**UPDATE**:

What I want is convert

`u'E:\\filemanager\\data\\c - \xe5\x89\xaf\xe6\x9c\xac'` to

either `u'E:\\filemanager\\data\\c - \u526f\u672c'` or `'E:\\filemanager\\data\\c - \xe5\x89\xaf\xe6\x9c\xac'`

`\xe5\x89\xaf\xe6\x9c\xac` can not be decode due to the `u` prefix, , that is the key problem!

---

**UPDATE2:**

my ajax code:

```
function ajax2(options) {

  var querystring = options.params ? urllib.format({ query: options.params }) : ''

  if (options.loading)
    swalShowLoading();

  reqwest({
      url: options.url + querystring,
      contentType: 'application/json',
      method: options.method || 'GET',
      data: JSON.stringify(options.data)
  })

}

// getFileList
// because this is a `GET` method, so no data be JSON.stringify here
// sorry for wrong explanation before.
ajax2({
  url: ApiUrl.list,
  params: {
    path: encodeURI(path)
  },
  success:success,
  error:error
})
```

Comment: "How to remove it" – Uhm, by removing it? That `u` is literally there in your source code, so you should be able to just delete it…?

Comment: what happens if you `print(p1)` ? Does it print it correctly ?

Comment: @Floran Gmehlin yes, p1 prints correctly. p2 fail only due to it has a redundant `u` prefix

Comment: Also, unicode strings can be *encoded* to bytes, and bytes can be *decoded* to unicode strings. You already have a unicode string there (leading `u`, *and* `unicode_literals`); your issue is that you're trying to *decode* that, which doesn't work.

Comment: Be careful with backslashes in strings. Either double them, or use a raw string. Do either of these work? `p1=ur"E:\filemanager\data\c - 副本"` or `p1u'E:\\filemanager\\data\\c - \u526f\u672c'`. IIRC, NTFS uses UTF-16 for unicode file names, eg `p1.encode('utf16')`, which should give `'\xff\xfeE\x00:\x00\\\x00f\x00i\x00l\x00e\x00m\x00a\x00n\x00a\x00g\x00e\x00r\x00\\\x00d\x00a\x00t\x00a\x00\\\x00c\x00 \x00-\x00 \x00oR,g'`

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: @PM 2Ring  it is fine to use `ur ` just for example. I would use `os.path.normpath` to format path in production .

Comment: @deceze  Yes, that's the problem , p2 is  already Unicode string which make it can not be decode.(But here p2 should not be add a `u` prefix, I think the problem is `unicode_literals`)

Comment: This would not have happened if you simply used Python 3. It forbids you mixing unicode and bytes pretty effectively.

Comment: @Jonas Wielicki  But how do I cope that string in python 2?

Comment: The question is, how did you get that string in the first place?  It is encoded as UTF-8 but decoded incorrectly.  Your `E:\` path indicates you are on Windows, so no UTF-8-encoded files exist.

Comment: I can tell you how to get the strings you want, but the root of the problem is how did you get the string in the first place?

Comment: @Mark Tolonen Filemanager webui first get the `path string`, send to frontend(browser), then I select a folder, want to list its children. So make a json post send the `path string` back, then  get `Windows Error[3]` when `os.listdir(path)`. I use pycharm debug and see the wrong `path string`.

Comment: So show how you sent the json post to send it back.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen I have update the question.Sorry for wrong , here no json be post, it is a `GET` method. All data are in querystring.

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is convert
>
> u'E:\filemanager\data\c - \xe5\x89\xaf\xe6\x9c\xac' to
>
> either u'E:\filemanager\data\c - \u526f\u672c' or 'E:\filemanager\data\c - \xe5\x89\xaf\xe6\x9c\xac'
>
> \xe5\x89\xaf\xe6\x9c\xac can not be decode due to the u prefix, , that is the key problem!

You can't decode Unicode strings.  The key problem is that a UTF-8-encoded byte string was decoded incorrectly in the first place.

Here's how to reverse it, but what you should really solve is why it was wrong to begin with.

`latin1` is a codec that converts the first 256 Unicode codepoints directly to bytes:

```
>>> s = u'E:\\filemanager\\data\\c - \xe5\x89\xaf\xe6\x9c\xac'
>>> s.encode('latin1')
'E:\\filemanager\\data\\c - \xe5\x89\xaf\xe6\x9c\xac'
```

So that "gets rid of the u".  You now have a byte string that can be decoded with UTF-8:

```
>>> s.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
u'E:\\filemanager\\data\\c - \u526f\u672c'
>>> print s.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
E:\filemanager\data\c - 副本
```

Comment: I never know `latin1` can do this, Thanks! And,  at first , I thought it's all `unicode_literals` fault. After some test I found remove `encodeURI` make flask read correct `path`. So it is a flask bug? it do something wrong to querystring

Comment: @twinmegami: `latin1` can only do this because the data was incorrectly decoded in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

`unicode` strings can be *encoded* to byte `str`.
`str` can be *decoded* to `unicode` strings.

When you have a `u''` string literal, *or* when you `import unicode_literals`, all your string literals will be `unicode` strings. You can only *encode* those, not `decode`. The error you get stems from an implicit conversion when you try to `decode` an already decoded `unicode` string.

```
>>> p1.encode('utf-8')
'E:\\filemanager\\data\\c - \xe5\x89\xaf\xe6\x9c\xac'
```

The `\x35…` represent the raw bytes (`str`) of your string.

```
u'E:\\filemanager\\data\\c - \xe5\x89\xaf\xe6\x9c\xac'
```

This is a `unicode` literal which literally expresses the text "\xe5…".
When you have a raw byte representation, you need to make sure Python treats it as a `str`, not as `unicode`:

```
>>> p2 = b'E:\\filemanager\\data\\c - \xe5\x89\xaf\xe6\x9c\xac'
>>> p2.decode('utf-8')
u'E:\\filemanager\\data\\c - \u526f\u672c'
```

The `b` prefix marks the literal as `str`, which can be decoded into a `unicode`.

`u''`, `''` with `unicode_literals` and `\u526f` are `unicode` → `encode` to `str`
`b''` and `\xe5` are `str` → `decode` to `unicode`

Comment: Not I add the `u`,  when my app get the path , it already be added a `u` prefix, how to convert the `u` to `b`  at this time??

Comment: Again: To convert from a `unicode` to a `str`, **encode** it. To convert from a `str` to a `unicode`, **decode** it.

Comment: What do you have, and what do you need? Do you need a `unicode`? Then having a `u` string is already what you want.

Comment: I want to convert `u'E:\\filemanager\\data\\c - \xe5\x89\xaf\xe6\x9c\xac'`  to either `u'E:\\filemanager\\data\\c - \u526f\u672c'` or 
`'E:\\filemanager\\data\\c - \xe5\x89\xaf\xe6\x9c\xac'`.

Comment: Because `os.path.exists(p2)` is False . p2 value go wrong. The correct value is p1

Comment: Again, you are typing that literal in, aren't you? What Python gives you is only `E:\\filemanager\\data\\c - \xe5\x89\xaf\xe6\x9c\xac`, you make a `u'E:\\filemanager\\data\\c - \xe5\x89\xaf\xe6\x9c\xac'` out of that. Which is wrong, see my answer. Or where else are you getting this `u'\xe5'` string from? If something is giving `u'\xe5'`, that means something has wrongly de/encoded the string at some stage. It's impossible to know that from your given example though.

Comment: I use json post(through browser, just plain `E:\filemanager\data\c - 副本`) to the flask app(filemanager).  I also confusing when I meet the `Windows Error[3]` which indicate `path not exists`. Then I use pycharm to debug my code, and see the string has already became `u'E:\\filemanager\\data\\c - \xe5\x89\xaf\xe6\x9c\xac'`  when `os.listdir(path)`.